# JavaFx Determining whether a mouse is clicking on the background or a Circle

Tags: javafx, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am creating a game where circles fall from the top of the screen to the bottom. When the circle is clicked its suppose to re-spawn in a random position on top of the screen and with a random color. I am pretty sure my problem has to do with my line to determine if the mouse click was on one of the circles or not is working correctly. So my questions are how would I determine if a mouse click happened on one of the circles or on the background screen? and What is wrong with the following line? (Because I am almost certain that my problem is from that line)

```
if((shape.get(i).getLayoutX() == e.getX())&&(shape.get(i).getLayoutY() == e.getY())){
```

My entire code is here:

```
public class ShapesWindow extends Application{
 final int WIDTH = 640;
 final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
 Random r = new Random();
 Circle circle;
 double yCord;
 long startNanoTime;

 Group root = new Group();
 Scene scene = new Scene(root, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
 Canvas can = new Canvas(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
 GraphicsContext gc = can.getGraphicsContext2D();
 ArrayList<Shape> shape = new ArrayList<>();

 @Override
 public void start(Stage theStage) throws Exception {
     theStage.setTitle("Click the bubbles!");
     theStage.setScene(scene);
     root.getChildren().add(can);
     gc.setFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE);
     gc.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

     /* This adds 10 circles to my Group */
     for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        gc.setFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE);
        gc.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        circle = new Circle(15,randomColor());
        root.getChildren().add(circle);
        circle.setLayoutX(r.nextInt(WIDTH+15));
        circle.setLayoutY(0);
        shape.add(circle);
    }

    /* This my attempt at trying to handle the Mouse Events for each thing */
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        shape.get(i).setOnMouseClicked(
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
                    public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                        shapeClicked(e);

                    }
                });
    }

    startNanoTime = System.nanoTime();
    new AnimationTimer(){
        public void handle(long currentNanoTime){
            double t = (currentNanoTime - startNanoTime) / 1000000000.0;
            yCord = t*20;

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                /* This if statment allows nodes to wrap around from bottom to top */
                if(yCord >=HEIGHT){
                    shape.get(i).setLayoutX(r.nextInt(WIDTH+15));
                    shape.get(i).setLayoutY(0);
                    shape.get(i).setFill(randomColor());
                    resetNan();
                }

                shape.get(i).setLayoutY(yCord);
            }
        }
    }.start();
    theStage.show();
}

 /*
  * This Function is suppose the change the color and position of the  circle that was clicked
  */
 public void shapeClicked(MouseEvent e){
    for(int i = 0; i < shape.size();i++){
        if((shape.get(i).getLayoutX() == e.getX())&&(shape.get(i).getLayoutY() == e.getY())){
            shape.get(i).setLayoutX(r.nextInt(WIDTH+15));
            shape.get(i).setLayoutY(0);
            shape.get(i).setFill(randomColor());
    }
 }

 /*
  * This allows the value of startNanoTime to be indrectly change it  can not be changed diretly
  * inside of handle() inside of the Animation class
  */
 public void resetNan(){
     startNanoTime = System.nanoTime();
 }

 public Color randomColor(){
     double R = r.nextDouble();
     double G = r.nextDouble();
     double B = r.nextDouble();
     double opacity = .6;
     Color color = new Color(R, G, B, opacity);
     return color.brighter();
 }
 public static void main(String[] args){
     launch(args);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    Shape s = shape.get(i);
    s.setOnMouseClicked(
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
                public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                    s.setLayoutX(r.nextInt(WIDTH+15));
                    s.setLayoutY(0);
                    s.setFill(randomColor());
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: It's not usual to use `layoutX` and `layoutY` to position a `Circle`: normally you leave those at `0` and set the `centerX` and `centerY` coordinates. `layoutX` and `layoutY` are the coordinates of the top left of the "layout bounds", which is a rectangle containing the node - so these are the coordinates of the top left corner of the smallest rectangle containing the circle. For a click to register on a circle, by default, you have to click on the actual rendered pixels of the circle, and of course the top left corner of its containing rectangle is not part of that area.

Comment: Consequently, your if statement is never true. It's generally a mistake to compare floating point values for equality anyway. It is obvious why my solution works, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I know long time passed by, but if anyone else need to check if a mouse click event was on a Circle or any other shape it is better to use the built in .contains method. Thanks to [Point2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Point2D.html) from JavaFx geometry class you can check if a click (x,y coordinate) is on a shape or not, you don't have to worry about the click position: in the center or border.

```
for (Circle circle:listOfCircles) {
                Point2D point2D = new Point2D(event.getX(),event.getY());
                if (circle.contains(point2D)){
                    System.out.println("circle clicked");
                }

            }
```